# Django - Select only specific rows from a query

Tags: django

I've started to learn django and as my first project I am trying to create a catalog.

I created 3 tables

1. Students
2. Catalog
3. Link table between those 2

This is how my models.py looks like:

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    Class = models.CharField(max_length =30)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Class)


class StudentiAn4(models.Model):
    Username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Group = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Username) + ' ' + self.FirstName +' ' + self.LastName


class CatalogStudenti(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog)
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentiAn4)
    grade = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.catalog) +' ' + str(self.student)
```

In views :

```
def studenti(request):
    query = CatalogStudenti.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'users/Studenti.html',{'query': query})
```

As a logged in user(*Username: 123, FirstName: test1, LastName: test1_LN*), I would like to see only grades assigned to me, not all grades.
Can you please tell me how can I filter the output so that I see only the grades assigned to me?

Current output:

```
123 test1 test1_LN - SEP 5
234 test2 test2_LN - ASC 4
123 test1 test1_LN - AACEP 6
```

Desired Output:

```
123 test1 test1_LN - SEP 5
123 test1 test1_LN - AACEP 6
```

Comment: I would suggest changing all the model field names to lowercase, especially since you currently have mixed styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the queryset in the view funtion to filter by the user field from student:

```
query = CatalogStudenti.objects.filter('student__Username'=request.user)
```

Comment: Won't this rely on whether the `__str__` method on the `User` model actually returns the `username`?

Comment: `Username` field in his code is just a `ForeignKeyField` to the `User` model. It has nothing to do with actual usernames.

Comment: yes, my fault, I missed it due to the somewhat weird naming. @flama, it might be a better idea to change the `StudentiAn4.Username` field to `StudentiAn4.User` (and to lowercase) since it points to the actual `User` model, rather than the `username`.